# Flyback Isolation Transformer Alternative

Tags: transformer, isolation, flyback

I am using the mEZS84801A as a reference design as shown below. It uses the MP8007 PoE chip. I have modified and tested this PoE system successfully and my camera be powered and it can run at 1 Gigabit.

[image]

The T2 coil 750316206 Wurth Np:Ns:Na=22:10:6, Lp=47.4μH, Core=EE13 47.4uH, cannot be found anywhere. The flyback transformer seems very specific to the designs, and the topologies seem to vary depending on PoE chip. I am having a lot of trouble trying to find an alternative for the design. My system runs on 12V and consumes ~10W.

I have read that it is a step-up transformer with very large ratios but I am also wondering if there is a way to use the transformer to output 5V to the system instead of 12V since most of my circuitry runs of 5V. I currently have a step down converter but seems like a waste of space. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: In theory it's straightforward to change the design to put out 5V, you would just change the divider ratio feeding the FB pin of the primary side regulation circuit.  You likely won't find an off-the-shelf transformer to do that, you'd have to design your own and have somebody manufacture it for you.  You could check with the IC vendor to see if they have done a design like that, they may have a transformer source already.  If you don't mind changing the controller, other vendors like TI or ADI/LT may have reference designs with magnetics sources.

Comment: Take a look at the TI TPS23755 controller as an alternative. In their evaluation board they use a different transformer: LinkCom LDT0950-50 (linkcomusa.com/jdownloads/Datasheets/ldt0950-50rspec.pdf). I'm not sure whether this will be any easier to purchase, though. As far as changing the output voltage with the MP8007 you may be able to do it just by reducing R1 to ~11.8kΩ. You may run into problems because the voltage at D4's cathode becomes too low to feed the controller through the Vcc pin, in which case it will use an internal LDO from Vdd what dissipates more heat, I believe.

Comment: I read more into the 5V and believe if I change R1 to 49.9K it will output 5V. Do you know of any substitute transformer I can use for this design? I assume winding ratio has to be the same. I can't find much info on the 3 winding transformer or many parts that have this configuration.